# MVC 5 Razor File Upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, file-upload, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to MVC 5 and I am trying to upload a file. But I always get redirected to the catch block. The problem is with the upload; I tried deleting the upload code and the try block was executed.

Here's the controller:

```
public ActionResult AddDemande()
    {
        Demande demande = new Demande();
        return View(demande);

    }

    [HttpPost]
          public ActionResult AddDemande(Demande demande, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                DemandeService demandeService = new DemandeService();
                demandeService.CreateDemande(demande);

                if (!file.ContentType.Contains("pdf"))
                {
                    TempData.Add("attension", "le cv doit être sous format pdf");
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Unable to save changes. Try again, le fichier joint doit être sous format pdf.");
                    return RedirectToAction("AddDemande");
                }

                demande.Date = DateTime.Now;
                demande.etat = "en attente";

                BinaryReader fileReader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);
                byte[] files = fileReader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
                demande.fichier = files;

                AdherentService adherentService = new AdherentService();
                Adherent adherent = (Adherent)Session["logedAd"];
                demande.nomBeneficiaire = adherent.nom;
                demande.eMailBeneficiaire = adherent.eMail;
                demande.beneficiare = adherent;
                adherent.listDemandes.Add(demande);
                adherentService.Updateadherent(adherent);
                demande.beneficiare = adherent;

                Session.Remove("logedAd");
                Session.Add("logedAd", adherent);

                return RedirectToAction("Login");

            }
        }

        catch
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

    }
```

and here's the part of the View that's responsible for the upload:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fichier, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input style="margin-left:0px;cursor:pointer;" type="file" name="fichier" id="fichier" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: visit http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1080/upload-files-with-model-data-in-mvc

Comment: Can you post what exception are you getting? catch (Exception ex) { };